# I have installed webpacker and but rails won't recognise javascript code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack

I am new to rails and I am making an Instagram clone for practice. For flash messages, I am using `toastr-rails` gem and javascript code where required But my app is not recognizing javascript script tags and the code is not executing. In the script tag, embedded ruby tags are white colored showing code is not recognized. here is my `application.html.erb` file code
`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Instagram</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5238639648.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

  <body>

    <%= render 'shared/navbar' if current_user %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <% if flash.any? %>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
          <% type = key.to_s.gsub('alert', 'error').gsub('notice', 'success') %>
          toastr.<%= type %>('<%= value %>')
        <% end %>
      </script>
    <% end %>

  </body>
</html>
```

On installing webpacker and adding gem webpacker in my app, nothing happened to my javascript folder as well, like no folder named `packs` was generated and I did that manually but still, my app won't recognize javascript and files with extension `js.erb`

Comment: rails version ?

Comment: i am using `rails 7.0.3`

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are using rails 7 which had removed the webpacker as there bundler for JavaScript.

You have to follow manual step to install webpacker.
This article has setup guide for webpacker
https://www.bootrails.com/blog/rails-webpacker-full-setup/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable.